# asp.net tracing custom implementation

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I want to do event tracing in asp.net.
That is whenever any method is called, i want to log some method specific details into a text file like method name, return value e.t.c

But, as requests will come from multiple clients, writing to a single file will lead to file getting locked and contention problems. can anyone pl suggest some easy way of doing this.

I am trying to use a custom tracelistener from system.diagnostics.tracing, but not sure how to handle problems due to multi-threading issues that i have mentioned above.

Any suggestion would be greatly helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

.NET Framework already has logging that you can easily use in your application.

The logging framework will handle the multithreading for you (and [`TraceSource` *is* thread-safe according the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx)). Under the hood, when the log file cannot be written (which is quite rare, since `TraceSource` uses a global lock internally, and doesn't necessarily flush every message to the file immediately), it will create another file with a GUID in its name (which ensures that [the name is unique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39771/240613)). For instance, if the main file is called `app.log`, it will create a file similar to `app-f24742d6-ec9c-44e6-8ba5-c0ef1a70dc00.log`.

Note that the files containing the logs are created automatically. The name of the file is configured through the configuration file (illustration in [point 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx), scroll the code to the right). Also, you are not limited to log files; you can for instance configure the application to log important messages to Windows Events.

The thread-safety of `TraceSource` means that you can make it static and call it from different instances (otherwise, you would be forced to create a `TraceSource` at instance level, which doesn't make much sense). This doesn't mean that there should be only one `TraceSource` in your application; the common pattern is to have one static `TraceSource` for every class which uses logging: this reduces coupling between classes, given that multiple `TraceSource`s use the same application configuration. [How to use TraceSource across classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391429/240613) provides an example of such pattern.

You may also want to look at how third-party log libraries solve the same problem. log4net is a popular alternative to .NET Framework's logging library, and:

> is thread-safe [...] - the framework manages everything for you.

<sup>Source: [Log4Net FileAppender not thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1294842/240613)</sup>

Also, if you're interested in logging *every* method, you may search for [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). One of the practical uses of AOP is to be able to trace every call to every method, without having to do the tedious task of including code related to logging in the methods themselves.